# SwiftでObjective-Cのクラスを使う際にNSStringDrawingOptionsがExpected a typeというエラーになってしまう

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

SWiftで行の高さを、文字数によって動的に変更したいと思っております。
対象はiOS7とiOS8のどちらにも対応予定です。

そこで以下の様なコードを書いたところエラーがでて使えませんでした。
どちらか片方のオプションを指定して場合は問題ないのですが、今回は２つとも必要だと思われます。

let options:NSStringDrawingOptions = (NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading)

このエラーについて調べたところどうもiOS7の不具合との情報を見かけました。
それでこのコードの部分だけをObjective-Cのクラスとしようとしたところ、
NSStringDrawingOptionsがExpected as typeというエラーになってしまうのですが通す方法はあるのでしょうか？

Bridging-Headerは作り、他のクラス（SDWebImage等）が無事動作していますのでその点は問題ないかと思ってます。

よろしくお願いいたします。

コードは以下になります。

DrawingOptions.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface StringDrawingOptions : NSObject
+ (NSStringDrawingOptions)combine:(NSStringDrawingOptions)option1 with:(NSStringDrawingOptions)option2;
@end
```

DrawingOptions.m

```
#import "StringDrawingOptions.h"
@implementation StringDrawingOptions
+ (NSStringDrawingOptions)combine:(NSStringDrawingOptions)option1 with:(NSStringDrawingOptions)option2
{
    return (option1 | option2);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Expected a type`というエラーメッセージはDrawingOptions.hのところで出ていると思いますので、DrawingOptions.hのimport文に`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`を足してください。

`NSStringDrawingOptions`はUIKitによる拡張なので、UIKitをインポートしないと、NSStringDrawingOptionsの定義が参照できません。

次に、StringDrawingOptionsが必要になるのはSwiftのバグ（厳密には`NSStringDrawingOptions`の定義がおかしい）なので、

```
let options:NSStringDrawingOptions = (NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading)
```

の箇所を

```
let options = StringDrawingOptions.combine(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, with: .UsesFontLeading)
```

と、StringDrawingOptionsで定義した、Objective-Cのメソッドを使ってビットマスクを計算するようにします。

Comment: UIKitをインポートすることで解決しました！
ありがとうございました！
本当に困り果ててましたので大変感謝しております。
ホッとしました。

Answer (score 2):

SwiftのEnum定義の中で列挙されてる値以外の値が入ったEnumオブジェクトを
Swiftでは作らせてもらえないようなので、
Objective-Cを経由して作ってしまうやりかたですね。本家で見たような気がします。

ですが、Swiftだけでも実は緊急手段の無理矢理キャストは可能です。

```
let options = unsafeBitCast(NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin.rawValue |
 NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.rawValue, NSStringDrawingOptions.self)
```

こちらの方が危険なところに危険と書いてある分オススメです。

Answer (score 1):

```
let options:NSStringDrawingOptions = 
    (NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin |
     NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading)
```

とりあえず、これを

```
let options:NSStringDrawingOptions.RawValue =
    (NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin.rawValue |
     NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.rawValue)
```

こう書きかえてみてください。少なくともエラーは消えるはずです。

C言語の `enum` と、 Swift の `enum` の仕様の違いを、お調べになる必要があると思います。

Comment: Swift の enumでは.rawValueと書くんですね。
今一度Swiftの列挙型について読んで確認します。
ありがとうございました。